# How to move to 2nd ViewController after data validation complete

Tags: ios, objective-c, validation, uiviewcontroller, uibutton

I'm creating a small app which verifies username and password from plist and shows user profile in other ViewController or (next screen).

- I added a Login Button which validates username and password from user input with data stored in Plist(property list).
- I also added a condition for show alert message  when user entered wrong password or logged in successfully.
- I created an another ViewController and connects  with main ViewController via Login button.
  my problem is when i clicked LOGIN button, it automatically  moves to next view controller without checking username password and also not shows alert.
  how to go next ViewController after validation completes and alert view done.

I need code in Objective-C

```
- (IBAction)submitButton:(UIButton *)sender {
    NSDictionary *dict = [[NSDictionary alloc] initWithContentsOfFile:[[NSBundle mainBundle]pathForResource:@"profileDetails" ofType:@"plist"]];
    NSString *usernameentered = dict[@"user"][@"username"];
    NSString *passwordentered = dict[@"user"][@"password"];
    if ([self.username.text isEqualToString:usernameentered] && [self.password.text isEqualToString:passwordentered]) {
        NSLog(@"login sucessfull");
        UIAlertController* alert = [UIAlertController alertControllerWithTitle:@"Attention"
                                                                       message:@"LOGIN SUCCESS"
                                                                preferredStyle:UIAlertControllerStyleAlert];

        UIAlertAction* defaultAction = [UIAlertAction actionWithTitle:@"OKAY" style:UIAlertActionStyleDefault
                                                              handler:^(UIAlertAction * action) {}];
        [alert addAction:defaultAction];
        [self presentViewController:alert animated:YES completion:nil];


    }else if ([self.username.text isEqual:@""] && [self.password.text isEqual:@""]) { UIAlertController* alert = [UIAlertController alertControllerWithTitle:@"Attention"
                                                                         message:@"PLEASE ENTER Valid EMAIL AND PASSWORD"
                                                                  preferredStyle:UIAlertControllerStyleAlert];

    UIAlertAction* defaultAction = [UIAlertAction actionWithTitle:@"Okay ! Got it" style:UIAlertActionStyleDefault
                                                          handler:^(UIAlertAction * action) {}];

    [alert addAction:defaultAction];
    [self presentViewController:alert animated:YES completion:nil];
    }

}
```

Comment: Please add the method called when you click on login button.

Comment: Unless you do not show any code to us, it is unlikely that anyone can help you.

Comment: @AndreasOetjen code added, please check!

Comment: @trungduc see edit! Thanks :)

Comment: i added all validation cases in my code. i just removed code of that cases here to avoid unnecessary code length. @Kuldeep

Comment: @SureshMopidevi, did you tried any answers?

Comment: Yes,  @Hitesh Surani's  code works easily.

Comment: @SureshMopidevi Glad to hear !!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you have use 'show' segue in tap of login button tap.you need to use custom segue for it. You can setup custom segue as below.

**Step 1:**

- Give custom segue to current controller to target controll. You can also see in below image.

[image]

[image]

**Step 2**
- Give any unique identifier to segue. You can also see in below image.

[image]

Then use below code for redirection when credential is valid.

```
[self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"NextVC" sender:self];
```

Answer (score 1):

> "i created an another view controller and connects with main view controller via Login button"

If you're using `segue` to navigate then you should write code inside `prepareForSegue` or `shouldPerformSegueWithIdentifier` method. Otherwise you can navigate to ViewController through code inside submit button action.

Try writing this code inside `shouldPerformSegueWithIdentifier` method, it should work

Answer (score 1):

[image]

```
- (IBAction)submitButton:(UIButton *)sender {

 //Get stored username and password
 NSDictionary *dict = [[NSDictionary alloc] initWithContentsOfFile:[[NSBundle mainBundle]pathForResource:@"profileDetails" ofType:@"plist"]];
 NSString *usernameentered = dict[@"user"][@"username"];
 NSString *passwordentered = dict[@"user"][@"password"];

 if ([self.username.text isEqual:nil] || [self.username.text isEqual:@""]) {

    //Show alert for empty username
 }
 else if ([self.password.text isEqual:nil] || [self.password.text isEqual:@""]) {

    //Show alert for empty username
 }
 else if (![self.username.text isEqualToString:usernameentered]) {

    //Show alert for wrong username
 }
 else if (![self.password.text isEqualToString:passwordentered]) {

    //Show alert for wrong password
 }
 else {


    //All validation is right.
    //Move to other Viewcontroller 

    UIStoryboard *main = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"Main" bundle:nil];
    NSString *Identifier = @"ViewController"; //Same as in storyboard

    UIViewController *vc = [main instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:Identifier];
    [self.navigationController pushViewController:vc animated:true]; //If you want to push
    //[self.navigationController presentViewController:vc animated:YES completion:nil] //If you want to present
 }
}
```